# Can I offer a bounty to a community wiki answer?

Tags: support, bounties

I read [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) but it's still not clear to me if I can offer a bounty to a community wiki answer?

Comment: Specifically: How does Community Wiki mode affect bounties?

Bounties are not affected by community wiki mode. When you award a bounty to an answer marked community wiki, the reputation bonus will be awarded to the user who posted the original revision of the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to award a bounty to a community wiki post.  In this case reputation bonus will be given to the original author of the post, regardless of the last editor.

Comment: What if the initiator of the answer is the same user who awarded the bounty?

Comment: @Nemo Then the bounty will cancel out and you've lost that rep.